# How can I change axis' scale(or intervals)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to adjust axis' scale (or intervals). 
On the other hand, I have some trouble with it.
Here's my code what I've implemented as below.

```
install.packages("randomForestSRC")
install.packages("ggRandomForests")

library(randomForestSRC)
library(ggRandomForests)

data(pbc, package="randomForestSRC") 
pbc.na <- na.omit(pbc)

set.seed(123) 
rsf <- rfsrc(Surv(days, status)~., data=pbc.na,     
             ntree=500, nplist=1, importance=T, proximity=T)

out.vs <- var.select (rsf)
gg_md <- gg_minimal_depth(out.vs)
```

In that case, the graph can be shown like this.

[image]

However, What I want to do is that adjusting x-axis scale from 0 to 22 by 1. 
So although I've conducted the added code as below, it didn't work.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

ggplot2::ggplot(gg_md, ggplot2::aes(x=varselect$depth, y=reorder(md.obj$count, varselect$depth))) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:22, labels=1:22) +
  ggplot2::geom_abline(slope=1, lty=2, color="red") +
  ggplot2::geom_hline(xintercept = attr(gg_md, "modelsize") + .5, lty=2, color="black")+
  ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

Please let me know how to do what I want to. 
Thanks always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From running your code, it seems like gg_md is a list and not a data.frame. ggplot doesn't know how to read it. That's the error that I got: `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class gg_minimal_depth/list`.

I'm using your sample data. 
Please see my adjustments to your code. From what I understood this what you wanted(?).

```
library(tidyverse)

 gg_md$varselect %>% 
  rownames_to_column("name") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=depth)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 22, by = 1),
                     limits = c(0, 22)) +
  geom_abline(slope=1, lty=2, color="red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = gg_md$modelsize + .5,
             lty=2, color="black") +
  theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Another question is that how I can make x-axis scale from 1 to 22 by 1. Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, it was indeed in your question. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. It's perfect!